# String concatenation: binary syntax v. operator <>

Tags: elixir

In elixir, are the following equivalent:

```
 str1 = "hello "
 str2 = "world"

 result = str1 <> str2
 result = <<str1::binary, str2::binary>>
```

??

Comment: You can also use string interpolation for the same result: `"#{str1}#{str2}"` which can be useful if variables can be numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The [`<>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%3C%3E/2) operator is a macro that transforms the code into the [`<<>>`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) special form.

```elixir
quote do str1 <> str2 end
|> Macro.expand(__ENV__)
|> Macro.to_string()
```

Output:

```elixir
"<<str1::binary, str2::binary>>"
```

Comment: Where is the defmacro for `<>`?

Comment: Okay, I found it: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1746.  The macro  extracts the `left` and `right` strings from `left <> right` and inserts them into a binary `<<left, right>>`.

Comment: That's right - the macro definition is linked from the official docs, which I linked to from the `<>/2` operator above, and the example I wrote demonstrates`str1 <> str2` being expanded into `<<str1::binary, str2::binary>>`

Comment: *the example I wrote demonstratesstr1 <> str2 being expanded into <<str1::binary, str2::binary>>* -- I was unclear how your example demonstrated that.  As far as I can tell, you created the AST for `str1 <> str2`, but then you call some additional functions on the AST to get the other result.

Comment: I posted some code in an answer.  If they are identical, why aren't the AST's identical?

Comment: The macro works differently for string literals, because it knows they're strings at compile time. Try it with variables, as you wrote in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're equivalent.

In Elixir, the `string` type is a [UTF-8 encoded binary](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#utf-8-and-unicode), so `"hello"` is `<<"h", "e", "l", "l", "o">>` or `<<104, 101, 108, 108, 111>>`.

The string concatenation operation is actually a binary concatenation operator so

```elixir
str1 <> str2 == <<str1::binary>> <> <<str2:binary>> == <<str1::binary, str2::binary>>
```